# Observability of non linear system using lie derivative

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, lie-derivative, kalman-filter

I want to design an EKF for a project, and i want to check the observability, in order to decide the sensor layout. I do not know about lie derivatives and lie algebra, but i with some research i think i understood the way to check local weak observability.  (The main source is this [pdf](https://www.rt.isy.liu.se/student/graduate/LinSys/lin/gesy2_4.pdf))

**I want to confirm** that my understanding is correct. So, here is what i think i have to do.
If my system is given by the following equation:
$$ \dot{x} =  f(x) $$
$$ y = h(x) $$

We compute the Lie Derivatives with the following way ( notation: $J_{g(x)}$ = the jacobian of the column vector function g(x) )?
$$ L_{f}h = \frac{ \partial h}{ \partial x} \cdot \dot{x} $$
$$ L_{f}h = J_h \cdot f(x) $$
$$ L_{f}(L_{f}h) = \frac{ \partial ( L_{f}h )}{ \partial x} \cdot \dot{x} $$
$$ L_{f}(L_{f}h) =  J_{L_{f}h } \cdot f(x) $$

and then we continue
$$ L_{f}\left(L_{f}(L_{f}h) \right) = \frac{ \partial \left(L_{f}(L_{f}h) \right)}{ \partial x} \cdot \dot{x} $$
and so on...

And then check if the rank of Q is equal to m, where Q is:

$$ Q = \left [ \matrix{ J_h \cr  J_{L_{f}h } \cr ... } \right] $$

**Edit** If the dynamics of the system are given by the equation:

$$\dot{x} = f(x,u) $$

Does the process of determining observability change?

Comment: Does the input depend directly on $u$?

Comment: The current model we are using is $\dot{x} = f(x)$, we have no input. Because it is a kinematic model of a car.

Comment: Then you should update the question with the actual model you are considering.

Comment: I   will update it, but i want the more general answer. The lectures also assume that there is input $u$

Comment: Yes, you can check the rank of that matrix. When an input is involved, the observability property will also depend on the value of the input.